# Get IDs in SQLite when a specific item in recyclerview is click

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

How can I get the id from my sqlite database if it's specific data was clicked on my recyclerview? To make it simple I have a database named "tblmynotes" that stores the following column name:

Terms, Definition, Syntax, and Code.

I have this recyclerview that displays only the "Terms" but when you clicked an item in the recyclerview it retrieve it's id from the column Terms as well as the data that are stored in it's column which is in Definition, Syntax, and Code. After that it displays the Definition, Syntax and Code in another activity which is a tablayout that has 3 tabs namely for each columns to display.

I've some attempts but was unable to see a solution because everytime I clicked an item in my recyclerview it restarts back to the main activity.

Here's my code:

My_Notes_View_TabFragment.java

```
 package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.viewNotes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;

public class My_Notes_View_TabFragment extends Fragment {

    private int position;
    public TextView content;



    public static Fragment getInstance(int position) {
        My_Notes_View_TabFragment f = new My_Notes_View_TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //get data from Argument
        position = getArguments().getInt("position");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_notes_view_tab_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        content = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //setContentView(); 



    }






}
```

My_Notes_View_Main.java

note the commented if/else statement inside the onTabSelectedListener, I'm not confident if it is correct.

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.viewNotes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;

public class My_Notes_View_Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final int numOfPages = 3; //viewpager has 4 pages
    private final String[] pageTitle = {"Definition", "Syntax", "Code"};
    private ImageButton addNew;
    private TextView content;
    My_Notes_View_TabFragment tabs = new My_Notes_View_TabFragment();




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_notes_view_main);

        content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);        

        addNew = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addNew);
        addNewTerms();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPages; i++) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(pageTitle[i]));
        }

        //set gravity for tab bar
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new My_Notes_View_MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), numOfPages);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(viewPager));

    }

    private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager pager) {
        return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
               /** 
                if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
                    content.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("note_def"));
                } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {

                    content.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("note_syntax"));
                } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {

                    content.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("note_code"));
                }
               */   

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        };
    }

  /**  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_notes_add_main_menu, menu);        
        return true;
    } */

    public void addNewTerms(){
        addNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add Button Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    });
    }

  /**  private void setContentView() {
        int position;
        if (tabs.getInstance(position) == 0) {

            content.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("note_def"));
        } else if (position == 1) {

            content.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("note_syntax"));
        } else if (position == 2) {

            content.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("note_code"));
        }
    }
*/
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }






}
```

My_Notes_View_MyPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.viewNotes;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.util.SparseArray;

public class My_Notes_View_MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int numOfTabs;
//private final SparseArray<Fragment> mPageReferences = new SparseArray<Fragment>();



    public My_Notes_View_MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       return My_Notes_View_TabFragment.getInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }


}
```

here is my custom adapter from my recyclerview
I'm not sure if the onClick method is correct.

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;
import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.mynote_databases.DatabaseHelper;
import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.viewNotes.My_Notes_View_Main;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<DataModel> items;
    Context context;
    static DatabaseHelper db;



    public CustomAdapter(List<DataModel> items, Context context){
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }



    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView textViewTerm;
        List<DataModel> items = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Context context, List<DataModel> items) {
            super(itemView);
            this.items = items;
            this.context = context;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


            this.textViewTerm = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTerm);

            //textViewTerm.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            DataModel item = this.items.get(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(this.context,My_Notes_View_Main.class);
            i.putExtra("note_id",item.getId());
            i.putExtra("note_def",item.getDefinition());
            i.putExtra("note_syntax",item.getSyntax());
            i.putExtra("note_code", item.getCode());
            this.context.startActivity(i);

        }


    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_notes_card_view, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(My_Notes.myOnClickListener);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view,context,items);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        holder.textViewTerm.setText(items.get(listPosition).getTerm());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


}
```

Lastly an additional info my datamodel since it define the data structure to display my data from the sqlite database into the recyclerview.

DataModel.java

```
public class DataModel {

    String term_;
    String definition_;
    int id_;
    String syntax_;
    String code_;

    public DataModel(){

    }

    public DataModel(int id, String term, String def, String syntax, String code) {
        this.term_ = term;
        this.id_ = id;
        this.definition_=def;
        this.syntax_=syntax;
        this.code_=code;
    }

    public DataModel(String term, String def, String syntax, String code) {
        this.term_ = term;
        this.definition_=def;
        this.syntax_=syntax;
        this.code_=code;
    }

   // insert getter and setter method here

}
```

As I already mentioned whenever I clicked on a specific items my app gets restarted thus returning to main activity. I'm not sure about the mistake since I dont understand what the logcat information is displaying considering that it was to short and has not enough information except that I have a nullpointerexception on my CustomAdapter.java inside the method ViewHolder

LogCat

```
03-17 03:05:20.177: D/AndroidRuntime(21473): Shutting down VM
03-17 03:05:20.177: W/dalvikvm(21473): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x55e06b20)
03-17 03:05:20.177: D/AndroidRuntime(21473): procName from cmdline: com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite
03-17 03:05:20.177: D/AndroidRuntime(21473): file written successfully with content: com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite StringBuffer : ;com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473): Process: com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite, PID: 21473
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3813)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes.CustomAdapter$MyViewHolder.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:57)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18442)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
03-17 03:05:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(21473):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the point where the crash occurs:
Inside the CustomAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    DataModel item = this.items.get(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(this.context,My_Notes_View_Main.class);
    i.putExtra("note_id",item.getId());
    i.putExtra("note_def",item.getDefinition());
    i.putExtra("note_syntax",item.getSyntax());
    i.putExtra("note_code", item.getCode());
    this.context.startActivity(i);

}
```

My_Notes.java
this is my recyclerview where Terms are being viewed it's adapter is in CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;
import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes.My_Notes_Add_Notes;
import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.mynote_databases.DatabaseHelper;

public class My_Notes extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static ArrayList<DataModel> data;
    static View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> removedItems;
    private ImageButton addNote;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_notes);

        //database
             db = new DatabaseHelper(this);


       //   myOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener(this);

        addNote = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addNotes);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_notes_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(db.getAllDataModel(),null));







        btnAdd();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    public void btnAdd(){
        addNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),My_Notes_Add_Notes.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

   /** public static class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
         DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
         private final Context context;



         private MyOnClickListener(Context context) {
             this.context = context;
         }

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             removeItem(v);
         }

         private void removeItem(View v) {
             int selectedItemPosition = recyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
             RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder
                     = recyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(selectedItemPosition);
             TextView textViewName
                     = (TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTerm);
             String selectedName = (String) textViewName.getText();

             int selectedItemId = -1;
             for (int i = 0; i < db.getAllDataModel.length; i++) {
                 if (selectedName.equals(DataModel.nameArray[i])) {
                     selectedItemId = DataModel.id_[i];
                 }
             }
             removedItems.add(selectedItemId);
             data.remove(selectedItemPosition);
             adapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedItemPosition);
         }

    }

*/
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: There is a NullPointerException in you onclick(). You can add logs to check what is null.

Comment: @Shadab I already did know that and it is in my MyViewHolder.onClick. But I don't know how to resolve that issue since I'm still far from comprehending how the codes work in android unlike php or any other web. I'm still a novice sorry.

Comment: Please paste the line at which crash occurs

Comment: @Shadab did you read my logcat (just wandering if it is posted or not)? It says that something is wrong on my CustomAdapter.java in it's onClick method inside the public static MyViewHolder. I already did post that. Have a look at the CustomAdapter.;java thank you.

Comment: Well, I was asking about the exact line in your code at which the crash occurs. If possible, paste the code with line numbers with fresh logs.

Comment: @Shadab I don't know what you mean by line numbers with fresh logs but ok I'll post the code though I'm not sure if that will be what your expecting.

Comment: Please add code where you are setting CustomAdapter

Comment: @Shadab Are you referring to the activity where the CustomAdapter is being used? I'll update it now.